# Converting char array to an int array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have  a char array containing *3 2 4 56 1*. I need to perform sorting function on the elements of the array (i have to arrange them in ascending order), but i can't unless they are numeric. how can i convert this array into an int array?

Comment: `for (auto c : myCharArray) {myIntegerVector.push_back(c) ; }` rock yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, a char array is numeric:

```
char nums[] = {1, 5, 2, 6, 0};

std::sort(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums));

for (auto it = std::begin(nums); it != std::end(nums); ++it)
    printf("%i ", *it);
```